# execvp and me; How can I make it work for me?

Tags: c, execvp

I have created a shell, and it works when I use system(1), but the specs say not to.
I am trying to use execvp at the end and I'm not really too sure on how to do it. Any chance of help would be appreciated.

Code ->

```
char *token = NULL;
char line[LINE_MAX];
char *line2 = NULL;
char *tempraryToken = NULL;
char *command = NULL;
char args[LINE_MAX];    

int numSpaces = 0;
int i;
int strleng = 0;
while( 1 )
{
    if( scanf(" %[^\n]", line) > 0) ) //prune off the newline char 
        token = strtok( line, ";" )   //break up different commands 
                                      //on the same line by ;
        do{
            strleng = strlen(token);
            for( i = 0; i < strleng; i++ )
            {
                if(token[i] == ' ') numSpaces++; //find out if there are spaces
            }
            i = 0;
            if( numSpaces >= 1 ) //if there are spaces
            {
                 line2 = token;
                 temporaryToken = strtok( line2, " ") //break by spaces
                 do{
                     //if it's before any spaces
                     if(i == 0){
                         command = temporaryToken;
                     }
                     else strcat(args, temporaryToken);
                 strtok( NULL, " ");
                 while (temporaryToken != NULL);
            }
        execvp(command, args); //this could be any of the exe commands
                               //that's what I'm looking for
        token = strtok( NULL, ";" ) //move to next token
        while( token != NULL );
}
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Isn't better to use fork() and waitpid until the process is finished?

Comment: I'm terrible at phrasing these questions - I'm looking for the right exe command to use here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, to keep running after `execvp` you need to `fork` your process, run `execvp` in child and `wait` or `waitpid` for it in parent. Having this in mind do some research of your own ;-)

Comment: Well, yes, if you need to communicate to its input and output.